# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong... here is my jquery code

```
  <script>

  $("#validationForm").submit(function(event) {

  alert('test');
  };
  </script>
```

Comment: change the `};` to `});`

Comment: Just as the error told you. You're missing a `)`.

Comment: Hello you forgot });

Answer (score 6):

```
$("#validationForm").submit(function(event) {

  alert('test');
};
 ^
```

Should be:

```
$("#validationForm").submit(function(event) {

  alert('test');
});
```

If you see this error in your browser's Dev Tools, try clicking in its line, like: `Syntax Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list       file.js:1`. When `1` is the line. It will show you where the error is.